# Selenium Automation Organize Project

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I would like to automate few applications. This application consist of web, mobile (Android + IOS) and API. How to organize this project for this situation.
Im automation in selenium using Java. In C#, once can create a project consists of multiple sub projects. How to do it in Java?

Please advise.

A billion thanks for your help.

Comment: You can Maven- multi module project e.g. https://mkyong.com/maven/maven-how-to-create-a-multi-module-project/  sln from .net would be pom.xml with module projects included

Answer (score 6):

It depends on which build automation tool you choose to work with.

When you work with C# you probably use [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019)

In Java Stack the most popular build automation tools are [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and [gradle](https://gradle.org/) and both support multi-module projects, It is up to you to choose which one suits your project requirements.

See

[Gradle vs. Maven](https://dzone.com/articles/gradle-vs-maven)

[Multi-Module Project with Maven](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module)

[Introduction to Gradle](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle)

[Maven Scopes and Gradle Configurations Explained](https://reflectoring.io/maven-scopes-gradle-configurations/)

Comment: Anyone please help. A billion thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I am not 100% sure what your goal is, but when it's about setting up Selenium (JAVA) projects and run them automatically, I can recommend you to use Maven & Jenkins to achieve this goal. Find further information in the following link:

https://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html

I hope I could help.